# How do I add free timeslots in fullcalendar / jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullcalendar

I am looking for a way to add in free timeslots in fullcalendar that show from 16:00 to 20:00 each day. So that they can be selected to book in an event, but not show on the times that there are events that I am fetching using a JSON call.

So far the call to get the dates from the database works fine, but not sure how to fill in greyed out boxes so that the user can click and add an event in. I am using a lightbox for that.

This is the code so far (but it creates an event even when there is one from the JSON callback):

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            eventClick: function(event) {           
                var url='api.php?getclassinfo=1&class_id='+event.id;
                $.getJSON(url,function(json){
                    $('#class_id').val(json.id);
                    $('#class_name').val(json.name);
                    $('#class_time').val(json.time);

                    var output='';
                    for (var i in json.day) {
                        output = output+json.day[i]+',';
                    }

                });
                return false;
    },
    //events: 'api.php?getdates=1&class_room='+class_room
    eventSources:
    [
    'api.php?getdates=1&class_room='+class_room,
     MyEvents
    ]
});


function MyEvents(start,end, callback) {
  var events = [];
  // Setup the meeting on the this weeks "monday"
  var meeting = new Date(start.getFullYear(),
                         start.getMonth(),
                         start.getDate(),
                         16, 00, 00);
  meeting.setDate((meeting.getDate() - meeting.getDay()) + 1);
    i=0;
  while (meeting <= end) {
    events.push({
      id: meeting.valueOf(),
      title: "Free space",
      start: newdate,
      allDay: false,
      backgroundColor: "#EEEEEE",
      borderColor: "#EEEEEE",
      textColor: "#AAAAAA"
    });
    // increase by one week
    meeting.setDate(meeting.getDate() + 1);
    i=i+1;
  }
  callback(events);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer on this thread might help you out. Not exactly an answer to your question as it does the oppsite, but you could probably just tweak the code slightly to achieve your goal.

[Disable timeslot ranges in jQuery fullcalendar plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008113/disable-timeslot-ranges-in-jquery-fullcalendar-plugin?rq=1)