# Disable timeslot ranges in jQuery fullcalendar plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am developing a webapp and am using [**jQuery fullcalendar plugin**](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/).

I need to somehow disable certain time-slots.

The current method I am using is to add events for the time-slots I want to disable and disallow event overlapping.

Is there a better way to do this? I rather not disallow event overlapping.

I can live with the solution for the above problem: adding black timeslots and disallow the adding of timeslots in those areas.

---

Nevertheless I have a more pressing problem. I need to be able to change the background color of slots for certain time ranges. Ideally I would be using this in the same way as the eventSources; just point to an url and send the to be colored ranges back with ajax/json.

The bounty I am about to add is for this last problem (colourized slot ranges, as well in day and week view). If someone can suggest me to another solution then full calendar that can do this, that's also fine.

Comment: no better idea yet; I just added black timeslots and plan to catch the events when someone makes or expands timeslots and disallow them to overlap with the black (disabled) slots. If I find a better way, I'll surely post it here.

Comment: Regarding you current solution. In week view when you disable a time slot, it gets disabled for the entire week. You cannot disable 6am-7am only for 6/8/2012. Right ?

Comment: yes you can; I just create a timeslot for a given period (if I am not mistaken the minimum is 15 minutes). further on, if anyone tries to create a timeslot overlapping with it, I will disallow it in the event handler. I plan to check on server side and am using ajax for this. Like you probably noticed; this project isn't finished yet, tbh it has some delay out of my hands, but soon I'll implement what I am telling you here; I already did some serious testing as proof of concept.

Comment: This user might be able to help you - he wrote the fullcalendar plugin. :) - http://stackoverflow.com/users/96342/arshaw

Comment: @techfoobar, perhaps those [**Answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/users/96342/arshaw?tab=answers) can provide a solution to this Question that somebody would like to create. He was last seen Nov. 2011 and his plugin website mentions *"It is up to you to add this functionality through FullCalendar's event hooks."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by using another calendar: jquery-week-calendar ( https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar ).

This calendar has a feature called Freebusy. It's ment to be used to have busy and free timeslot ranges, but by altering the source code a bit, I am able to add background colors to timeslot ranges. I changed the method freeBusyRender as follows:

```
freeBusyRender: function(freeBusy, $freeBusy, calendar) {
    if(freeBusy.free == 't_red') {
        $freeBusy.css("backgroundColor", "red");
    } else if(freeBusy.free == 't_green') {
        $freeBusy.css("backgroundColor", "green");
    } else if(freeBusy.free == 't_blue') {
        $freeBusy.css("backgroundColor", "blue");
    } else if(freeBusy.free == 't_black') {
        $freeBusy.css("backgroundColor", "black");
    }
    $freeBusy.addClass('free-busy-free');
    return $freeBusy;
}
```

Then, I can initialize the calendar as follows:

```
(function($) {
    d = new Date();
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - (d.getDay() - 3));
    year = d.getFullYear();
    month = d.getMonth();
    day = d.getDate();
    var eventData2 = {
        options: {
            timeslotsPerHour: 4,
            timeslotHeight: 12,
            defaultFreeBusy: { free: true }
        },
        events: [
            { 'id': 1, 'start': new Date(year, month, day, 12), 'end': new Date(year, month, day, 13, 00), 'title': 'Lunch with Sarah'},
            { 'id': 2, 'start': new Date(year, month, day, 14), 'end': new Date(year, month, day, 14, 40), 'title': 'Team Meeting'},
            { 'id': 3, 'start': new Date(year, month, day + 1, 18), 'end': new Date(year, month, day + 1, 18, 40), 'title': 'Meet with Joe'},
            { 'id': 4, 'start': new Date(year, month, day - 1, 8), 'end': new Date(year, month, day - 1, 9, 20), 'title': 'Coffee with Alison'},
            { 'id': 5, 'start': new Date(year, month, day + 1, 14), 'end': new Date(year, month, day + 1, 15, 00), 'title': 'Product showcase'}
        ],
        freebusys: [
            { 'start': new Date(year, month, day - 1, 8), 'end': new Date(year, month, day - 1, 18), 'free': 't_red'},
            { 'start': new Date(year, month, day, 8), 'end': new Date(year, month, day + 0, 18), 'free': 't_green' },
            { 'start': new Date(year, month, day + 1, 8), 'end': new Date(year, month, day + 1, 18), 'free': 't_blue' },
            { 'start': new Date(year, month, day + 2, 14), 'end': new Date(year, month, day + 2, 18), 'free': 't_black'},
            { 'start': new Date(year, month, day + 3, 8), 'end': new Date(year, month, day + 3, 18), 'free': 't_red' }
        ]
    };
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $calendar = $('#calendar').weekCalendar({

        allowCalEventOverlap: true,
        overlapEventsSeparate: true,
        totalEventsWidthPercentInOneColumn: 95,

        timeslotsPerHour: 4,
        scrollToHourMillis: 0,
        height: function($calendar) {
            return $(window).height() - $('h1').outerHeight(true);
        },
        eventRender: function(calEvent, $event) {
            if (calEvent.end.getTime() < new Date().getTime()) {
                $event.css('backgroundColor', '#aaa');
                $event.find('.wc-time').css({
                    backgroundColor: '#999',
                    border: '1px solid #888'
                });
            }
        },
        eventNew: function(calEvent, $event, FreeBusyManager, calendar) {
                    calEvent.id = calEvent.userId + '_' + calEvent.start.getTime();
        },
        data: function(start, end, callback) {
                    callback(eventData2);
        },
        displayFreeBusys: true,
        daysToShow: 7,
        switchDisplay: { '1 day': 1, '3 next days': 3, 'work week': 5, 'full week': 7 },
        headerSeparator: ' ',
        useShortDayNames: true
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

which gives me following result:

[image: calendar]

I bet this can be improved; I think I broke the freeBusy feature doing this, but I don't need it.

Answer (score 7):

BTW, Why don't you check it in `Select` callback?

```
select: function( start, end, allDay, jsEvent, view ) {
    if( /*start is the disabled time*/ )
        return false;
    else{
        // Proceed with the normal flow of your application
        // You might show a popup to get info from user to create
        // a new event here
    }
}
```

Comment: Adil, thank you for your suggestion. I am already planning on doing something similar. What I am looking for is a way to make it visually clear to the user that certain timeslots are disabled, so they see it before they click on it. The solution for this till now is to create black events.

Comment: Although an Answer is **not yet found**, you received the Bounty because you participated during the Bounty period. The purpose of this Sponsored Bounty is now complete, which was to attract attention that may have lead to a viable answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

Using Fullcalender, in my code I have something like this:

```
var availablePeriods = [["8:00", "12:00"], ["13:00", "17:00"]]; //these are the time intervals when the slots are OPEN

if (availablePeriods !== undefined) {
  slots = $element.find('.fc-agenda-slots tr');

  /* first add 'closed' class to all slots, and then remove class from 'open' slotts */
  slots.addClass('experdscheduler_closedSlot');
  if (jQuery.isArray(availablePeriods)) {
    /* only in weekview and dayview */
    currentView = plugin.getView();

    if (currentView === 'agendaWeek' || currentView === 'agendaDay') {
      numberOfAvailablePeriods =  availablePeriods.length;

      scheduleStartTime = timeToFloat($element.fullCalendar( 'option', 'minTime'));            
      scheduleSlotSize = $element.fullCalendar( 'option', 'slotMinutes') /60;

      /* function to calculate slotindex for a certain time (e.g. '8:00') */    
      getSlotIndex = function(time) {
        time = timeToFloat(time);            
        return Math.round((time-scheduleStartTime)/scheduleSlotSize);
      }


      /* remove 'closed' class of open slots */                 
      for (i=0; i<numberOfAvailablePeriods; i++) {            
        startOfPeriodSlot = getSlotIndex(timeToFloat(availablePeriods[i][0]));
        endOfPeriodSlot = getSlotIndex(timeToFloat(availablePeriods[i][1]));

        for (j=startOfPeriodSlot; j<endOfPeriodSlot; j++) {
          slots.eq(j).removeClass('experdscheduler_closedSlot');
        }
      }          
    }
  }         
}

/**
 * Helper function: Converts a given time to a float, e.g. '8:15' becomes 8.25
 * @param mixed time A integer, float or a string. Valid strings: '8:15', '20:15', '8:15am', '8:15pm', '8.15', etc.
 * @license http://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php GNU Public License
 * @author Koos van der Kolk <koosvdkolk at gmail dot com>
 * @return float
 **/
function timeToFloat(time) {      
  var returnValue, timeAsArray, separator, i, timeSeparators = [':', '.'], numberOfSeparators;

  /* is time an integer or a float? */
  if (parseInt(time, 10) === time || parseFloat(time) === time) {
    returnValue = time;
  } else {
    /* time will be considered a string, parse it */
    time = time.toString();

    numberOfSeparators = timeSeparators.length;

    for (i = 0; i < numberOfSeparators; i = i + 1) {
      separator = timeSeparators[i];

      if (time.indexOf(separator) > 0) {
        timeAsArray = time.split(separator);

        returnValue = parseInt(timeAsArray[0], 10) + parseInt(timeAsArray[1], 10) / 60;

        /* does string contain 'p' or 'pm'? */
        if (time.indexOf('p') > 0 && returnValue <= 12) {
          returnValue = returnValue + 12;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return returnValue;
}
```

The above code is a compilation of parts of a plugin I made, so it might not work directly. Feel free to contact me.

Comment: This makes it possible to have open and closed slots for certain periods, right ?

Comment: Well, not really: It adds a class to 'closed' slots, so they can e.g. be given a gray background color. But this is what you wanted, or not?

Comment: Check http://nl.picturepush.com/public/8749184 for screenshot (weird, I cannot add it to my original post...)

Comment: well, I wanted to be able to give multiple background colors to multiple ranges; as you can see, I answered my own question by using jquery-week-calendar. But still, thank you for your input!

Comment: Congratulations with the bounty; your answer is not completely what I was looking for, but it was the closest.

Comment: Hi koosvdkolk, Could you please explain, if I want to implement how do I do that?

Answer (score 5):

I finally got this available slots to work per days.

adjustment of koosvdkolk's answer to have different available slots per days:

```
   function adjustWorkHourSlotSize(day_num) {
      $(".day"+day_num+"slot").width($(".fc-col"+day_num).width()-2);

   }

   function addWorkHours2(availablePeriods, calendar_element) {
       if (availablePeriods !== undefined) {
          numberOfAvailablePeriods =  availablePeriods.length;

          //slots.addClass('nySchedule_unavailable_slots'); 
          //iterate trough days and get avail periods for each day of week
          currentView = calendar_element.fullCalendar('getView');
          currentView =  currentView.name;
          if (currentView === 'agendaWeek' || currentView === 'agendaDay') {



            scheduleStartTime = timeToFloat(calendar_element.fullCalendar( 'option', 'minTime'));            
            scheduleSlotSize = calendar_element.fullCalendar( 'option', 'slotMinutes') /60;
            /* function to calculate slotindex for a certain time (e.g. '8:00') */    
            getSlotIndex = function(time) {
              time = timeToFloat(time);            
              return Math.round((time-scheduleStartTime)/scheduleSlotSize);
            }

            slots_content = calendar_element.find('.fc-agenda-slots tr .ui-widget-content div');
            for (var i=0; i!=numberOfAvailablePeriods; i++) {
              if (currentView === 'agendaWeek') {

                slots_content.append("<div class='day"+i+"slot dayslot'></div>");
                $(".day"+i+"slot").addClass('unavailable');
                adjustWorkHourSlotSize(i);
              }


              dayPeriodsLength=availablePeriods[i].length;
              for (var j=0; j!=dayPeriodsLength; j++) {
                start=availablePeriods[i][j][0];
                end=availablePeriods[i][j][1];

                startOfPeriodSlot = getSlotIndex(timeToFloat(start));
                endOfPeriodSlot = getSlotIndex(timeToFloat(end));
                for (k=startOfPeriodSlot; k<endOfPeriodSlot; k++) {
                  $(".day"+i+"slot").eq(k).removeClass("unavailable");
                }
              }                
            }
          }
       }
   }
```

now just call:

```
var availablePeriods = [ [["8:00", "16:00"],["3:00", "5:00"]], [["9:00", "14:00"]] ];
addWorkHours2(availablePeriods, $("#calendar"));
```

and dont forget css classes:

```
.dayslot {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.fc-agenda-slots .unavailable{
  background-color: #e6e6e6;

}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to implement your code, but I dont' manage to make it work, I made a jsFiddle, could you help me out? http://jsfiddle.net/sebababi/w64Hd/

Comment: His code is a bit outdated, and at this point incomplete. If you still need assistance, perhaps I can help you Sebastian. 
However, this is only a visual indicator of available periods.

Answer (score 4):

[This thread](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=144) in google code allows to follow the evolution of this kind of issue. Actually it's about busyness hours colors, but it is directly linked

Also [this guy](https://github.com/elhigu/fullcalendar) has implemented a very handy way to manage this purpose still using fullcalendar with this kind of code

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    ....
    events: [
        {
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: new Date(y, m, 1)
        }
    ],
    annotations: [{
        start: new Date(y, m, d, 13, 0),
        end: new Date(y, m, d, 15, 30),
        title: 'My 1st annotation', // optional
        cls: 'open', // optional
        color: '#777777', // optional
        background: '#eeeeff' // optional
    }]      
});
```

Check the [screenshot](http://content.screencast.com/users/Mikaelle/folders/Jing/media/85a7bb79-fa01-4602-99e0-b1958a0d37d2/00000002.png)

Comment: Hi, the screenshot looks amazing, and I'm trying to implement your code, but I don't manage. I made a jsFiddle. What am I doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/sebababi/g5gtG/2/

Answer (score 1):

Fullcalendar has a builtin function `businessHours` which emphasizes certain time slots on the calendar.

```
businessHours: [ // specify an array instead
{
    dow: [ 1, 2, 3 ], // Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday
    start: '08:00', // 8am
    end: '18:00' // 6pm
},
{
    dow: [ 4, 5 ], // Thursday, Friday
    start: '10:00', // 10am
    end: '16:00' // 4pm
}
]
```

Answer (score -7):

There is another much more developed and supported calendar type plugin from dhtmlx called the scheduler here: http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/

It supports disabling of timeslots, background colours, and much more. I've used it before and found it offers everything I needed.

[image]

Comment: I've worked with this plugin and it's not to much dynamic :/