# Flowing-in fullcalendar events? An impossible layout? Pic included

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

Here's a mockup of what I'm looking for. Please forgive the chocolate smudges:

[image: mockup]

I think this is impossible with fullcalendar, after looking at the html it generates: (It doesn't lay out each day individually. Instead, the events fit into horizontal elements that stretch the width of the entire calendar.)  But I figured I'd ask anyhow: How can I do this?

Question 2: If impossible, can anyone recommend a calendar widget that **can** do this? It shouldn't be hard, if designed from the ground-up to support this kind of layout.

FYI: My reason for wanting this is to fully display all the **kinds** of events that are available on particular days. Basically, to be able to show more than 3 or so events per day in the month view. Then, when a user hovers or clicks, I'll show time and details for a particular day.

Comment: Please share sample code or demo using jsfiddle

Comment: Here is an example of how you can make your own custom build of fullcalendar.js (hope it helps) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279394/fullcalendar-with-twitter-bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible because if you assigned the event for two days meany its will show the event message for two day so it will occupied the two column full width.Because it will show the message to the user event for two days.

If you assigned the event for single day its will occupied the full width. and text event will be in the second line only.

Comment: Hi thanks! And do you know if it's possibile to build fluid events that don't stay over each other?