# Disable a time slot jquery fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm working on a scheduling system with  [jquery fullcalendar plugin](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/). Getting available timing for an individual.

```
 minTime: msg.d.Records.startHour,
 maxTime: msg.d.Records.endHour
```

It's working fine. But now i want to disable certain hours(lunch break). How can I do that? These hours will come from web service.

Comment: can you please give more context/code? are you using this: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ ?

Comment: yes im using arshaw calender. e.g. i want to disable 1pm to 2pm slot in calender daily/weekly view.

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008113/disable-timeslot-ranges-in-jquery-fullcalendar-plugin but you’re out of luck – they don’t yet have an answer either... =(

Answer (score 0):

You could generate events for the unavailable time and use a specific color to indicate unavailability. Then, if someone tries the save a new event, before creating a new event object, you could loop through existing events to see if there is a conflict. If conflict, cancel event generation and display a message to user. Or, you could utilize similar strategy using select callback (not to be confused with select method).