# checking event date is valid using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, fullcalendar

I have created an application using fullcalendar, the application is working fine, but the problem which i am facing is the events is sharing the time which is been allocated to them through dragging and dropping like as shown below. Since my requirement is that the any events should not share their time with any other events.

I have posted this issue over **[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27225049/events-sharing-each-other-in-full-calendar)**

so for solving this i came up with this like i have a sets of sated like as shown below

```
[
{start : '2014-11-13T12:00:00', end : '2014-11-13T14:00:00'},
{start : '2014-11-13T14:30:00', end : '2014-11-13T16:00:00'}
]
```

and i have to check whether the date time where i am placing is used by some other event or not

say datetime `{start : '2014-11-13T11:00:00', end : '2014-11-13T12:00:00'}`

should **pass** for

```
{start : '2014-11-13T10:30:00', end : '2014-11-13T11:30:00'}
```

should **fail** for

```
{start : '2014-11-13T13:30:00', end : '2014-11-13T14:30:00'}
```

using javascript

Comment: Use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: @Nit 2.8.4/moment.min.js is there  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arttyb44/)

Comment: Then what's the problem?

Comment: @Nit have you seen my jsfiddle,

Comment: @Nit there undr week, event can share time through dragging, that i want to prevent, only if it is placed at an unalocated time, it should apply

Comment: @AlexMan you could use the function below and if it returns true then add it else don't add it...

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service, questions should be about specific issues, not just _"I need this"_.

Comment: @Nit i did'nt mean like that

Comment: That's simply all your question is at the moment. You've shown no piece of programming that you're having a problem with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using code like this to check if the date is already in the set this is just an example but this function should return true or false depending on if the date is ok or not:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var test = [
{start : '2014-11-13T12:00:00', end : '2014-11-13T14:00:00'},
{start : '2014-11-13T14:30:00', end : '2014-11-13T16:00:00'}
];
var test1 = {start : '2014-11-13T13:30:00', end : '2014-11-13T14:30:00'};

if(checkDates(test, test1))
{
    window.alert("Ok");
}
else
{
   window.alert("Error");
}
function checkDates(test, test1)
{
    var returnBoolean = true;
    for(var i = 0; i < test.length; i++)
    {
       if(((new Date(test1.start)) >= (new Date(test[i].start)) && (new Date(test1.start)) <= (new Date(test[i].end))) || ((new Date(test1.end)) >= (new Date(test[i].start)) && (new Date(test1.end)) <= (new Date(test[i].end))))
       {
           returnBoolean = false;
           break;
       }
    }
    return returnBoolean;
}
</script>
```

Comment: i have applied but not working....look this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aez30w17/2/), in that go to week and drag an event and place with as well as without overlapping other event, i am not able to place over the events as well as to other place too, see the console

Comment: Why don't you debug it your new end date is null when you try to print to console you are trying to access format() of `console.log('new end date ->',event.end.format()); ` even though event.end is null.  The function should work for you you just need to figure out how to use it with your code...

Comment: @AlexMan Try testing my code separately and you should see that the function works you just need to implement it correctly within your code...